# Flutter + firebase + stripe

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, stripe-payments

I am a newby about stripe an its integration in a flutter app.

I am using firebase for my backend (not really anything to complex, just some event functions) and as I said, flutter for my app (for android an iOS) and I am totally lost with how to proceed.

I have found a plugin for firebase (https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/stripe-firestore-stripe-payments) and also a library for flutter for stripe (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe) but I am not sure if I have to use one of those and do the other part by myself, if using one will be redundant with the other or if I should use both and integrate them together.

Extra info: payments will be one off each month (not a subscription, every month will be a different amount) and the will be stored in a firestore collection.

So... Any clear resource or documentation will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Stripe Extensions for Firebase are based on Cloud Functions and Firestore. This means that to initiate an action with Stripe, you write something to a document in Firestore, and to get a response or respond to an event on Stripe, you'l listen to/read from Firestore.

There is a client-side [SDK for this extension](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/web-sdk/firestore-stripe-web-sdk/README.md) for JavaScript, but not for other platforms/languages yet. To learn how to interact with Stripe through the Extension on other platforms, consider starting with this [codelab](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/next/codelab-steps/index.lab.md), which covers use-cases such as [reading product and pricing data and render it to the page](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/next/codelab-steps/index.lab.md#read-product-and-pricing-data-and-render-it-to-the-page), [creating a subscription for your customer](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/next/codelab-steps/index.lab.md#create-a-subscription-for-your-customer), and [showing the active subscription once created](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/next/codelab-steps/index.lab.md#show-the-active-subscription-once-created).

From the documentation page you linked comes this on its [recommended usage](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/stripe-firestore-stripe-payments#recommended-usage):

> If you're building on the web platform, you can use this extension for any of your payment use cases.
>
> If you're developing native mobile applications and you're selling digital products or services within your app, (e.g. subscriptions, in-game currencies, game levels, access to premium content, or unlocking a full version), you must use the app store's in-app purchase APIs. See Apple's and Google's guidelines for more information.
>
> For all other scenarios you can use the stripe-android, stripe-ios, stripe-react-native, or flutter_stripe SDKs.

So that last line links to the `flutter_stripe` SDK you also mention, and recommends using that for use-cases not met by the Stripe Extension for Firebase.

Comment: OK, thank you. I should use flutter_srripe and write my own cloud functions.